# How to get css properties set explicitly via the style attribute?

Tags: javascript, css

How do I find all the css properties set explicitly via the style attribute?

Comment: I mean using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you wanted to get the styles of an element named "myp":

```
var stylez = document.getElementById("myp").style;
var ix;
for (ix = 0;  ix < stylez.length;  ++ix) {
    console.log(stylez.item(ix) + ": " + stylez.getPropertyValue(stylez.item(ix)));
}
```

Working [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uk9Tw/1/) produces output:

```
font-weight: bold
```

Only the info in style is output, even though a class sets a font size and a CSS directly applies a background color.

You could also read the style attribute text and parse it yourself, which is less accurate but if you wanted to include invalid statements you'd need this.

Comment: +1 seems to work in FF and Chrome at least. Setting the style with JS may return properties that weren't defined solely in the style attribute, but executing this before any other code should take care of that though.

Comment: Doesn't work in ie7 and ie8 but works in ie9.

Comment: You didn't specify IE8 or below.  In those crippled browsers you would have to parse the text yourself, which is somewhat difficult.

Answer (score 1):

*element*.style.cssText returns the text value of the style attribute of *element*

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there’s a really cross-browser way to do that, and I wonder whether you really need to get at those properties. But you could iterate over the properties of the element’s `style` property. The problem is that on some browsers, the `style` property has array like properties and the `cssText' property. You can explicitly drop them out (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdd8Y/)):

```
var s = document.getElementById('s');
var styles = document.getElementById('myp').style; 
var prop, value;
function CSSify(val) {
  var i, ch;
  var css = '';
  for(i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    ch = val.charAt(i);
    if(ch.toUpperCase() === ch) { 
      css += '-' + ch.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      css += ch;
    }
  }
  return css;
  } 
for(prop in styles) {
  value = styles[prop];
  if(typeof value === 'string' && value !== '' && prop !== 'cssText' && 
     isNaN(parseInt(prop)) ) { 
    s.innerHTML += CSSify(prop) + ': ' + value + '<br>';
    }
}​
```

However, browsers differ in how they interpret the `style` attribute value as regards to properties or property values that they don’t recognize. There are even differences between IE versions: IE 9 drops a property with an unrecognized property name, whereas IE 7 drops a property with an unrecognized property value. Moreover, IE seems to add `accelerator: false`.